# ORACLE 18c XE (18.0.0.0.0) - MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED (COLLATE BINARY_CI) problem

Tags: plsql, oracle-xe, collate

I set **MAX_STRING_SIZE** from **STANDARD** to **EXTENDED** with this command:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET MAX_STRING_SIZE=EXTENDED SCOPE=spfile;
```

This query is finished with "Done".
I checked it with this command:

```
SELECT * FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'max_string_size';
```

..and here is the result in multirows format:

```
NAME                    max_string_size
VALUE                   EXTENDED
DISPLAY_VALUE           EXTENDED
DEFAULT_VALUE           STANDARD
ISDEFAULT               FALSE
ISSES_MODIFIABLE        FALSE
ISSYS_MODIFIABLE        IMMEDIATE
ISPDB_MODIFIABLE        TRUE
ISINSTANCE_MODIFIABLE   FALSE
ISMODIFIED              FALSE
ISADJUSTED              FALSE
ISDEPRECATED            FALSE
ISBASIC                 FALSE
DESCRIPTION             controls maximum size of VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, and RAW types in SQL
```

I would like to use **COLLATE BINARY_CI** in a **CREATE TABLE** and I have the following error message:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_db 
  (
       sample_column VARCHAR2(50) COLLATE BINARY_CI
  )
```

> **ORA-43929: Collation cannot be specified if parameter**
> **MAX_STRING_SIZE=STANDARD is set**

Oracle Version is: ORACLE 18c XE (18.0.0.0.0)

Comment: You can follow oracle documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321.
You can use oracle home variable, to execute scripts, as @${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/utl32k.sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was I tried to modify value of *MAX_STRING_SIZE* parameter in **CDB** instead of **PDB**.

Modify commands with 'XEPDB1':

```
PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 CLOSE IMMEDIATE;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 OPEN UPGRADE;
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB1;
ALTER SYSTEM SET MAX_STRING_SIZE=EXTENDED;
@?/rdbms/admin/utl32k.sql;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 CLOSE;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE XEPDB1 OPEN;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite as simple as ALTER ...; See [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C):

> Use ALTER SYSTEM only when the database is in UPGRADE mode, and run
> the utl32k.sql script afterward, as explained in this section. 
> ...  
> The COMPATIBLE initialization parameter must be set to 12.0.0.0 or
> higher to set MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED.

Comment: I did it in UPGRADE mode and ran the utl23k.sql without any errors. No change.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321 at section 'Increasing the Maximum Size of VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, and RAW Columns in a PDB'.

Commands run with sysdba user:

```
# list pdbs
show pdbs;

# alter session to a specific pdb
alter session set container = {pdb};

# restart pdb in upgrade mode
shutdown;
alter pluggable dabase {pdb} open upgrade;

# change max_string_size
alter system set max_string_size=extended;

# run oracle script
@${ORACLE_HOME}/admin/utl32k.sql;

# reopen as normal mode
shutdown;
alter pluggable database {pdb} open READ WRITE;

# recompile invalid objects
@${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql;
```

I used https://hub.docker.com/r/pvargacl/oracle-xe-18.4.0 container image. The page has guidelines for connectiog to sysdba mode.